# how to add name number email id to my mysql database

Tags: mysql, html

i have created a website with shared hosting from a company and i have created themes and fronted end development is completed. now the problem is

```
If some one visited my site and entered their details in temple having name, mail,number.
So how i can see those name and email and number in my mysql database.
```

I have installed mysql database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assuming visitors already have filled a HTML `<form>` element and data are inserted into the database, you will need to execute a `SELECT` statement to get the visitors details.**

```
SELECT name, mail, number FROM [tableName]
```

Here's a PHP example :

```
<?php
$host = "127.0.0.1";
$user = "myuser";
$pass = "mypass";
$bdd = "mydatabase";

try {
$objBdd = new PDO("mysql:host=$host; dbname=$bdd; charset=utf8", $user, $pass) ;
$objBdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
} catch(Exeception $prmE) {
    die('Error : ' . $prmE->getMessage()) ;
}

$getMyVisitors = $objBdd->query("SELECT name, mail, number FROM myTable");
while ($visitorData = $getMyVisitors->fetch()) {
echo "----\r\n";
echo "Name : " . $visitorData['name'] . "\r\n";
echo "Mail : " . $visitorData['mail'] . "\r\n";
echo "Number : " . $visitorData['number'] . "\r\n";
echo "----\r\n";
}

$getMyVisitors->closeCursor();
$objBdd = NULL;
```

Every statements using dynamic user data (example: username, password, comments ...) should be prepared.
If you want to use a `WHERE` condition, use prepared statements like

```
$getMyVisitors = $objBdd->prepare("SELECT name, mail FROM myTable WHERE number = ?");
$getMyVisitors->execute(array("+33000000000"));
```

**Now, if the visitors informations are not saved in the database, you will need to create a HTML `form` element.**

Your HTML `form` element should looks like :

```
<form action="myScript.php" method="POST">
<input type="submit" value="Send my informations">
</form>
```

Where myScript.php is a PHP script that will save the visitor's informations into the database. Use my example above to make that script, you will need to use an `INSERT` statement.

You will need to add `input` elements in the `form` as much as you need, in your case, three (name, mail, number).
Note that you will need to set the `name` attribute to each of your inputs to be able to get the inputs value in your PHP.
Example : `<input type="email" name="visitorMail">` goes with `$myVisitorMail = $_POST['visitorMail'];`.

Comment: tq for your reply, I an new to this thisng. here from whre the php script will take name mail and number.

Comment: Here, PHP will connect to the database `$bdd` and then will fetch the informations from the `myTable` table.
Is your form already sending visitors informations to your database ?

Answer (score 0):

You Could directly use php to do this task! The sample code would get you going around!
You could view there details by firing query like

SELECT Name,Phone,Email FROM Customers

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```